# Royden 8.2 - Criterion for convergence in $L^2(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem from Royden

> 16. Let $E$ be a measurable set, $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ a sequence in $L^{2}(E)$ and $f$ belong to $L^{2}(E)$. Suppose
>     $$
>     \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} f_{n} \cdot f=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} f_{n}^{2}=\int_{E} f^{2} .
>     $$
>     Show that $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ converges strongly to $f$ in $L^{2}(E)$.

Here is my solution.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\|f_{n}\right\|_{2} \\
&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_{E} f_{n}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&=\left(\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} f_{n}^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&=\left(\int_{E} f^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&=\|f\|_{2} \quad \text { So } f_{n} \rightarrow f \text { in } L^{2}(E)
\end{aligned}
$$

Why is this not correct?

The solution manual online gives this as the solution

16. By linearity of integration, we have
    $$
    \int_{E}\left(f_{n}-f\right)^{2}=\int_{E} f_{n}^{2}-2 \cdot \int_{E} f \cdot f_{n}+\int_{E} f^{2}
    $$
    Taking limits, we obtain
    $$
    \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E}\left(f_{n}-f\right)^{2}=0
    $$
    Therefore $\left\{f_{n}\right\} \rightarrow f$ in $L^{2}(E)$.

EDIT
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We say $f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}(E)$ if $\|f_n-f\|_2 \to 0$. Covergence of $\|f_n\|_2$ to $\|f\|_2$ is not enough for convergence in $L^{2}(E)$.

Comment: I thought in my class, we saw a theorem if the norms converge then the functions converge in L^p where $1\leq p < \infty$

Comment: That is certainly false. Consider constant functions $f(x)=(-1)^{n}, f(x)=1$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: What about the image that i just edited in the question. This is straight from my professors course notes.

Comment: Almost everywhere convergence is not given here.

Comment: Ah of course thank you!